# Printer Ricoh SP 213w in ubuntu

Tags: printing, ricoh

Does anyone has a hint how to install new Ricoh SP 213w printer? Im not able to find a ppd file but I got a .plc file from Ricoh containing some information about the machine. Is there a possibiliy to make a use of it?

Thanks in advance

frank

**Update:**

Printers -> Add -> Select the printer from the network -> select "Generic" -> "PCL 5e"

makes the printer print something reasonable, though the margins dont seem right.

**Solution:**

selecting "Generic" -> "PCL 6/PCL XL" seems to work better.

Answer (score 2):

The only one actually working for me is the Generic PCL Laser Printer (grayscale), the other ones (Pcl5/6) used to work not any more.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/631833)

Comment: @ElderGeek This seems like an answer to me.

Comment: @Seth Seems like a comment to me.

Comment: @Seth It's an answer in form of a comment. What is it you don't understand and what is that 'requires clarification'? Now I am the one who 'requires clarification'.

Comment: Exactly this, only owned mine since 2016 and in 2022 PCL5/6 no longer work. Generic PCL Laser Printer (grayscale) works. Thanks. I couldn't recall which PCL6 driver had worked but "Generic PCL 6/PCL XL Printer Foomatic/pxlmono" does not.

Answer (score 1):

I added the printer via its IP Address and chose the
Generic" -> "PCL 6/PCL XL LF CUPS+Gutenberg
Driver.(a slight change to the above driver)
The Testpage describes the fitting PPD as STP01497.PPD
Hope that helps.